# Finding largest farthest increasing pairs in array?

Tags: arrays

Is there a simple linear algorithm for finding in an array A two such elements that $A[i] > A[j]$ and $i - j$ is as large as possible? If one wants to actually return the indices, then linear memory usage seems impossible to avoid. If the only result needed is the value $i - j$, i.e. the distance, can we get away with less than linear memory?

Obviously, one can use constant memory if one is willing to loop over all pairs (i, j).

Comment: By the way, if you have a sublinear (by memory) algorithm for finding the value $d = i - j$, then you can just iterate through $A$ and for each $i$ compare $A[i]$ and $A[i + d]$ thus finding a concrete pair of indices also in sublinear memory and without increasing time complexity.

Comment: See also: [Subhasis Das' solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18282220).

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to assume that in your question, $i > j$ holds as well (if there is no such pair of values, then you have a nonincreasing array and the problem is trivial).

The two alternatives you've pointed out in your post are

- $O(n)$ additional memory and $O(n)$ time
- $O(1)$ additional memory and $O(n^2)$ time

An "intermediate" solution, for example, is to pick $O(\frac{n}{B} + B)$ additional memory and $O(n \cdot \left(\frac{n}{B} + B)\right)$ time. To do this, divide the array into continguous blocks of size $O(B)$, and so the number of blocks is $O(\frac{n}{B})$. For each block, store only the minimum value of the block in an array `block_minimum`.

Say you're at the $i$-th index. The goal is to find the first index in the array where the value of the corresponding element is greater than `A[i]`.

First, for all preceding blocks, find the first block $j$ for which `block_minimum[j] < A[i]`. If such a block exists, scan that block and find the first index $k$ belonging to the block for which `A[k] < A[i]`. The index $k$ is the first index of the array for which `A`. There are $O(\frac{n}{B})$ preceding blocks.

However, if such a block doesn't exist, then second, iterate on preceding elements in the current block (there are $O(B)$ of them).

The combination of the two steps consumes $O(\frac{n}{B} + B)$ time for an index $i$. So the overall time usage is $O\left(n \cdot \left(\frac{n}{B} + B\right)\right)$ and the extra memory usage is $O\left(\frac{n}{B}\right)$ (the number of blocks).

If we choose $B = O(\sqrt n)$, we obtain a solution that uses $O(\sqrt n)$ memory and $O(n \sqrt n)$ time. This technique is commonly known as *square-root decomposition*.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it seems that there is no comparison-based linear time algorithm for this problem. Though I have no formal proof yet.

If we assume that array $A$ consists of only positive integer values and each value is bounded by $O(n)$ (here and after $n$ is a length of an array $A$), then we can use an idea of counting sort to get a linear time algorithm. That is, let's create an array $B$ such that $B[i]$ stores a pair of numbers: minimum and maximum index of elements (let's denote them $B[i].min$ and $B[i].max$) in array $A$ with value $i$. Obviously, we can compute $B$ in $O(n)$ time using a single run through $A$. Then let's iterate through $B$. On $i$-th iteration let's maintain a value $ M_i = \min_{1\leq j< i} B[j].min$. And let's compute $S_i = B[i].max - M_i$. The maximum over all $S_i$ is an answer to your problem. Time and memory complexities of this algorithm (under specified assumptions) are both $O(n)$.

Comment: If the array is in descending order except a[k+1] > a[k] then you need to examine a[k]. Which is of course the last array element you look at.

Comment: @gnasher729 Please, can you provide some minimal example illustrating your idea? I am afraid, I can't understand what is your point.